# How to mark session as non-bounce in Google Analytics

Tags: ajax, google-analytics

I understand that Google Analytics takes a user session as a "Bounce" if the user visits one page and no more.

If we have a site that is extremely AJAX heavy and the expected behaviour is that most users won't visit the site more than once, then is there a way to programmatically declare to Google Analytics that this particular user session should not be treated as Bounce?

On our code side, we will then measure a session as "non-bounce" when they take a meaningful action that is equivalent of visiting a second page on a non-AJAX site.

This makes the bounce rate a useful metric for us.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way is to lodge a virtual pageview in your ajax callbacks, at least if the ajax call changed the content to an extent that makes the result effectively a new page (i.e. ga send with a pagepath as the third parameter; the path does not have to physically exists but should relate to the content returned by the ajax call).

If the content does not change significantly you can send an event in the ajax callback - make sure NOT to use the non-interaction flag, so the event is used in calculating bounce rates.

Comment: Hay nice and helpful.can you please illustrate more.

Comment: @eike Can you kindly add an example JS call for either option please?